# Add to Cart Not Working 404 error Custom .phtml

Tags: jquery, magento, http-status-code-404, url-routing, cart

I am trying to figure out why my ItemController is not working properly. I built a custom extension and custom .phtml file. I am trying to figure out why I am getting a 404 error.

**Here is the relevant code in my custom view.phtml file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!CDATA[
        var registryItemsForm = new Validation($('registry-items'));
        var registryProductsCheckFlag = false;

        function addSelectedGItemsToCart() {
            var url = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/addselected'); ?>';
            var cels = new Array();
            $$('.items-checkbox').each(function(el){
                if( $(el).checked ){
                    cels.push($(el).value);
                }
            });
            var separator = (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) ? '&' : '?';
            $$('#registry-items .qty').each(
            function (input, index) {
                for(var i=0; i<cels.length; i++){
                    if(input.name=='qty['+cels[i]+']'){
                        url += separator + input.name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input.value);
                        separator = '&';
                    }
                }            
            }
        );
        setLocation(url);
        } 

        //]]>
        </script>



<div class="buttons-set">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add Selected to Cart') ?>" onclick="addSelectedGItemsToCart()" class="button btn-add"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add Selected to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

Now this seems to be doing its job because when I get the 404 the url looks like this

```
mysite.com/registry/index.php/registry/view/addselected/?qty[2]=5
```

However, my **ItemController** is not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in your javascipt

`$this->getUrl('*/registry/addselected')` instead of `$this->getUrl('*/*/addselected')`

Let's me know any problem occurs. Hope help :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Maybe this is where the problem lies. Here is the full address. `mysite.com/registry/index.php/registry/view/addselected/?qty[2]=5` I tried your suggestion but still got the 404. Any idea now that you can see the whole url?

Comment: So, var url = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/addselected'); ?>'; please alert(url). Let me know your result

Comment: Ok, so if I add this to the script `var url2 = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/addselected'); ?>';
alert('<?php echo($url2); ?>');` the alert box is empty on both the registry page and after I submit the add to cart function.

Comment: Just added this below the defined url under the submit function. `alert('<?php echo($url); ?>');` Same thing. It is empty

Comment: You rock for pointing me in the right direction!!!!! Thanks so much. I fixed it by doing the following. `$this->getUrl('registry/item/addselected');`